# Best way to send EF data from SignalR server to .NET client

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, signalr

Prelude:

On server side i use EF6.1 code-first to work with DB and i have **TestData** class that represents DB table structure. I want to send that data to client but i don't want to implement additional wrapper classes. I thought that this problem could be solved by interface implementation, but it seems that SignalR can't deserialize interface data on client (haven't found anything that could help to solve this approach as it looks very good).

I suppose i can declare **TestData** class in a shared library and send it directly to client but this approach breaks the single EF code-first classes storage logic.

Is there any other possible solution for this problem?

Comment: Just in case you do not know about it, if your client has the definition of a type which has the same shape as the one of the server, you can use that one to deserialize your data object on the client. No need to shere assemblies. In case it's new to you, it's one more element that could help you in taking your decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be using concrete implementations not interfaces. Just use a JavascriptSeralizer to convert your data to json and send it as a single parameter to the client. Then on the client convert it back to an object using JSON.Parse.

Comment: Yeah, i think i should stick with this logic this time.